# MUI error message alert showing although i dont want it to

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, conditional-operator

so I'm having some issues in my code which I'd like to get help with.

as you can see the error alert box is showing although it is supposed to be empty.
I ran some code "tests" to see what is happening and rendered it on the page.

[image]

consts -

```
const [displayMessage, setDisplayMessage] = useState({});
const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState({
username: "",
email: "",
password: "",
});
```

useEffects -

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      setMessage(`${data.userName} has been created successfully`);
    }
  }, [data.userName, success]);

 useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof errorMessage === "string") {
      setDisplayMessage(errorMessage);
    } else {
      setDisplayMessage(
        Object.keys(errorMessage).map((key) => {
          return errorMessage[key];
        })
      );
    }
  }, [errorMessage]);
```

ternary operators -

```
        {typeof displayMessage} // "test"
        <br />
        {displayMessage.length} // "test"
        {Object.keys(displayMessage).map((key) => {
          console.log(displayMessage[key]);
        })}
        {displayMessage &&
          (typeof displayMessage === "string" ? (
            <Alert sx={{ mb: 4 }} severity="error">
              {displayMessage}
            </Alert>
          ) : (
            <Alert sx={{ mb: 4 }} severity="error">
              {Object.keys(displayMessage).map((key, index) => {
                return <div key={index}>{displayMessage[key]}</div>;
              })}
            </Alert>
          ))}
```

now as you can see here it's working the way I want it -

[image]

my only problem is that the alert box shows empty.

Comment: Those `useEffect`s look like they should really be `useMemo`.

Answer (score 0):

Objects such as `{}` don't have a `length`, so checking that's useless.

There's no point in trying to check the truthiness of the `displayMessage` object either, since empty objects are truthy:

```
> !!{}
true
```

If you want to figure out if an object is "empty" to hide the alert altogether, you could use e.g. `Object.keys(displayMessage).length === 0`.

All in all, I'd rewrite the alert-displaying bit to be a separate component that can deal with falsy values; then, deriving error messages from other state should be `useMemo`, not `useEffect`:

```
function MessagesAlert({message}) {
  if (!message) {  // No message.
    return null;
  }
  if (typeof message === 'string') {
    return <Alert sx={{mb: 4}} severity="error">
      {message}
    </Alert>;
  }
  const keys = Object.keys(message);
  if (!keys.length) { // No keys in message object.
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <Alert sx={{mb: 4}} severity="error">
      {keys.map((key, index) => {
        return <div key={index}>{message[key]}</div>;
      })}
    </Alert>
  );
}

function Component() {

  const errorMessages = React.useMemo(() => {
    const errors = {};
    if (something) errors.username = 'Username is required';
    return errors;
  }, [something]);

  return <MessagesAlert message={errorMessages} />;
}
```